# How to use multisig commands?

Tags: tezos-client

A bunch of new awesome commands are out in tezos-client man:

```
  sign multisig transaction on <multisig> setting delegate to <dlgt> using secret key <key>
  sign multisig transaction on <multisig> withdrawing delegate using secret key <key>
  sign multisig transaction on <multisig> using secret key <key> setting threshold to <threshold> and public keys to [<key>...]
  from multisig contract <multisig> transfer <qty> to <dst> on behalf of <src> with signatures [<signature>...] [--fee <amount>]
  set delegate of multisig contract <multisig> to <dlgt> on behalf of <src> with signatures [<signature>...] [--fee <amount>]
  withdraw delegate of multisig contract <multisig> on behalf of <src> with signatures [<signature>...] [--fee <amount>]
  run transaction <bytes> on multisig contract <multisig> on behalf of <src> with signatures [<signature>...] [--fee <amount>]
```

Is there any tutorial/examples on to how to use that:

- with tezos-client
- with RPC calls (general guidelines contribute to our favorite libraries)

At least a general purpose list of steps, what kind of calls to do in which order / how does this orchestrate with contract origination and calls, and how to leverage this to enable access control in contracts would resolve the question.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any tutorial/examples on to how to use that with tezos-client

Not really a tutorial but a typical workflow is described in [the merge request introducing this feature](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/merge_requests/1010).

> how to use that with RPC calls

There is nothing specific to the multisig smart contract at the RPC level. Adding support for multisig authentication in wallets and libraries requires to port [the client code](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/master/src/proto_alpha/lib_client/client_proto_multisig.ml).

> how to leverage this to enable access control in contracts

A current limitation of this multisig contract is that it can only transfer to `contract unit` which means that it cannot pass a parameter to another smart contract. To overcome this limitation, [a more generic multisig contract](https://github.com/murbard/smart-contracts/blob/master/multisig/michelson/generic.tz) has been proposed but it is not yet supported by `tezos-client`.

You might also be interested by [this multisig wrapper](https://assets.tqtezos.com/multisig-wrapper).